# excel vba replace range cell

Tags: vba, excel

This code is already working, but i want "plain" & "Letter" to be dynamic. Like pointing to specific range cell. I've tried it but it wasn't successful.

Basically sReplace = Replace(sReplace, Range"A1", "Range"B1:B10")

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sFind As String
    Dim sReplace As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim newFileName As String

    FilePath = "C:\Users\new\Plain.prn"

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Input As iFileNum

    Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sFind
    sReplace = sReplace & sFind & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close iFileNum

    sReplace = Replace(sReplace, "plain", "Letter")

    'SaveAs txtfile
    newFileName = Replace(FilePath, ".", "_edit.")
    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open newFileName For Output As iFileNum

    Print #iFileNum, sReplace
    Close iFileNum
    End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Replace a Range of cells with a specific value from another cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to make the values pointing to a given range in a given worksheet:

```
With Worksheets("NameOfTheWorksheet")
    sReplace = Replace(sReplace, .Range("A1"), .Range("A2"))
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you are asking:

Replaces the values in Range `B1:B10` where it matches `sReplace`, with the value from Range `A1`

```
Range("B1:B10").Replace What:=sReplace, Replacement:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```